# Scale size of shape when shape gets RenderTransformed

Tags: wpf, transformation

In my application, I apply a TransformGroup to an image. The TransformGroup consists of a ScaleTransform and a TranslateTransform so that i can zoom in and out and shift the image by using the mouse. On the image I want to set some points and visualize them by setting shapes at these point positions. When I zoom in or out or shift the image, the shapes are to remain at their positions in the image. In order to achiev this I apply the TransformGroup of the image to the shapes too. This works fine. Now the problem is that the shapes size is scaled too. But I want it to remain the same.

I hope that I could explain my problem well enough.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use the RenderTransform directly for the shapes. Instead you should transform only their positions by the image's RenderTransform, most certainly somewhere in code behind. Get the transform matrix by `RenderTransform.Value` (or from your internal transform object) and use the Matrix methods on the coordinate points.

Comment: Yes, that's an idea. Nevertheless i was interested if it's possible to avoid that RenderTransform affects the size of the shape. I will do it as you described it

Answer (score -2):

I would try to put the inner shapes into another scaletransform with "inverted" scaling factor, that means that the final scaling factor of the shapes is always 1.

Comment: You can't "put shapes into a scaletransform". Without any further explanation this is a useless answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sascha. But this does not work because the position of the shape depends on the coordinates of the point which i set by using the mouse. And these coordinates are transformed internally by RenderTransform. But RenderTransform also affects the rendered width and heigth of the shape. So i want to decouple the transformation of the size from the one of the coordinates.